# Magento v1.9.x How do you customize the head code for the Product Detail Page only?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9, magento-1.8

I want to add OG tags to the product detail page in Magento for the PDP (product detail page) only.

Is there a way to add code in between the head tags for the PDP only?

The two approaches I'm thinking of:
1) is there a head.phtml for the PDP only that I can edit (that I just don't know about)?
=-OR-=
2) adjust the regular head include and somehow look at the page and dump out the data that way.

NOTES(this is for):
Magento v1.x (my store is updated to 1.9.2).
The code is product data only meant for the PDP.

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll need to check current page is product detail page then you have to check by either by controller or router . Here we have checked using the controller .
Go to to head.phtml file write following code .

```
<?php
 $this->getRequest()->getControllerName();
if($this->getRequest()->getControllerName()=='product') {?>
    <?php // write your og tag here for eg. ?>
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />


<?php }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can target product detail page using handler `catalog-product-view`. Make `local.xml` in your theme and add

```
    <catalog_product_view>
      <reference name="head">
        // your action
       </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
```

in your action you can try `<action method="addCss”>` or                   `<action method="addJs">` or `<![CDATA[ / ]]>` to set anything in header.

Answer (score 0):

```
<? if(Mage::registry('current_product')){ //your product page only code } ?>
```

The above if statement should return true only if you're on a product page.
You should be able to use this to add product page exclusive code to your head.phtml